# vimdiff - Custom file name possible while we export?

Tags: scripting, vim, vimdiff

I am comparing 2 files in a script and exporting to html file (Below is the syntax i am using). When the file get saved, its saving in a name called Diff.html by default. Is there a way we can save it in a different name while executing?

Script:

```
vim -d $filename1 $filename2 << EOF
:TOhtml
:wqa
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9927057). Use `:sav myfile.html` followed by `:qa`.